# mercurial child projects not showing up as java projects after cloning the parent

Tags: mercurial-subrepos

I have a mercurial project as shown below:

Parent : Project 1 which is a folder with java files etc.

Project 2, Project 3 and Project 4 are child projects meaning they reside under the Project 1 folder again with their own java files and other associated files.

When I clone the parent project(Project 1) into eclipse, I do see the child projects as a part of my check out. However, when I make any changes to the java files in the child projects, they dont seem to behave like a normal java file. Rather no errors shown in eclipse and they dont seem to build automatically.

I want to know if this behaviour is normal or my only option is to clone the individual child projects to see them as java projects. Meaning clone Project 2, then Project 3 and so on.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.